# nginx - open() failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: apache, nginx

I ran this tutorial: http://www.schenkels.nl/2014/12/reverse-proxy-with-odoo-8-nginx-ubuntu-14-04-lts/#comment-822
I did it on Debian Wheezy and it worked. But when I did the same thing on Debian Sqeez, it does not work.

In nginx log I see these errors:

```
2015/05/07 07:20:17 [error] 6419#0: *6 open() “/var/www/longpolling/poll” failed (2: No such file or directory), client: IP_address, server: localhost, request: “POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1″
```

Do I need to do something differently on Squeez (maybe there is some older nginx)?

Site config looks like this:

```
upstream odoo8 {
server 127.0.0.1:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream odoo8-im {
server 127.0.0.1:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

## http redirects to https ##
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;

# Strict Transport Security
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
# server port and name
listen 443;
server_name _;

# Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
# as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
client_max_body_size 200m;

# add ssl specific settings
keepalive_timeout 60;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;

# limit ciphers
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# increase proxy buffer to handle some OpenERP web requests
proxy_buffers 16 64k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;

#general proxy settings
# force timeouts if the backend dies
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

# set headers
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

# Let the OpenERP web service know that we’re using HTTPS, otherwise
# it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

# by default, do not forward anything
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;

location / {
proxy_pass http://odoo8;
}

location /longpolling {
proxy_pass http://odoo8-im;
}

# cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
# under heavy load this should relieve stress on the OpenERP web interface a bit.
location /web/static/ {
proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
proxy_buffering on;
expires 864000;
proxy_pass http://odoo8;
}
}
```

P.S. If it is important, Odoo location is in `/opt/odoo/odoo`

**Update**
It seems something strange have happened. I tried to default back to apache. But now it is also not working. I get same thing:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/longpolling
```

**Scenario this happened**. Reverse proxy was running on apache (didn't have such errors before). I installed nginx. tried to run it, it didn't run. I thought it was clashing with apache (even though before installing nginx I stopped apache), so I uninstalled apache. Then I noticed that error with nginx. Then I removed nginx and installed apache, but now it still gives same error.

What could cause it? The only thing I actually did, was to install nginx. Could it alter those directories in some way?.. How can I fix it now?

**Update2**
With apache, I managed to restore back how it was working. There actually `proxy_http` was not enabled. But with nginx, still the same problem.
Also on Squeez, it installs nginx version only `0.7.6`, when on Wheezy it is `1.2.1`. Maybe that older version works differently and I need to adjust it somehow differently?

**Update3**
Installed nginx from backports (now it is 1.2.1 version). Now it is running, but not quite properly. In nginx log I get these messages now:

```
2015/05/08 07:54:09 [error] 32494#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP address, server: _, request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8072/longpolling/poll", host: "db.host.eu", referrer: "http://db.host.eu/web"
```

Also had to delete `default` site symbol link, because with it, it was just loading welcome to nginx screen. The strange part is, that reverse proxy for location `/` works, but for `/longpolling` connection is refused. Can it be because of apache2? For now I didnt't uninstall it, but stopped it.

Comment: yes it seems your nginx version is quite old, it might be that one of the directive does not work. The result is that your proxy_pass directive seems to not be taken into account.  You should consider upgrading it (for security reason also). 1.2.1 is actually in squeeze backports packages

Comment: @Pixou I installed from backport, it is now running, but now got another problem (updated in question)

Comment: then you should try connecting directly to your 8072 port, probably there is something wrong on this service that is proxied

Comment: @Pixou I tried telnet 127.0.0.1 8072. It returns connection refused. For some reason this port is never used, but in configuration this port is specified to be used (actually it is default port for longpolling). To be specific, it should be used when another paremeter `workers` is set to greater than `0`. But the strangest part is that this port is never used only in Debiant distros (both Squeeze and Wheezy), but there is no such problem on Ubuntu. But I guess this is another Question, cause that error was solved by updating nginx.

Comment: the idea of this nginx config is to proxy request to the server on port 8072. So if you have no server running on this port, this can't work. I don't know odoo but from the link you posted, I understand it's the openERP server. That's what you should focus on making work. Did you try : sudo service odoo-server restart and
sudo service nginx restart ?

Comment: @Pixou Yeah, thats why I wrote it is another Question (cause I noticed about port not being opened). And that question is why that port is not used, when it should be. Sure I tried restarting both servers, but it does not help. There might be some incompatibility with Debian distro and Odoo, because as I said, there is no such problem on Ubuntu.